# HYPALLAGE: He nodded his agreeing head

Tags: syntactic-analysis, figures-of-speech

> **HYPALLAGE**: a figure of speech in which the usual relations of words/phrases are **interchanged**, e.g. "*He nodded his agreeing
> head*."
>
> Microsoft® Encarta® 2009. © 1993-2008 Microsoft Corporation

What such [interchange](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypallage) is shown in the example *He nodded his agreeing head* ?

Comment: What is agreeing, him or his head?

Comment: What was he doing with his other head?

Answer (score 2):

*“He nodded his head, agreeing.”* is not the same as *"He nodded his agreeing head."*

In *“He nodded his head, agreeing”*, agreeing is an adverb = in agreement.

In *"He nodded his agreeing head"*, agreeing is an adjective modifying "head".

*"He nodded his agreeing head"* is not a good example of hypallage as it means *He nodded his head that was nodding in agreement.* which is nonsense.

A good example of hypallage is "On the **idle hill** of summer/Sleepy with the flow of streams/Far I hear..." (A.E. Housman, A Shropshire Lad) — "Idle", although syntactically modifying "hill", semantically describes the narrator, not the hill. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage).

Answer (score -1):

“He nodded his head, agreeing.” Is the normal word order.

Hence”head” and “agreeing” are the words the order of which is interchanged.

The inversion is to be avoided as it implies that it is his head, rather than he, that  was agreeing. It also might suggest that  he has another head that disagrees.

Comment: "He nodded his head in agreement" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed it would, and I considered adding it as a rider, but as the question is about interpreting an example from a publication rather than one devised by the poster, I thought it better not to confuse the issue. Perhaps write to Bill Gates. And if you think my interpretation correct, don’t be embarrassed to upvote it. That way the poster will know.

Comment: @HotLicks Another alternative (though not an alternative explanation of this example) is to place agreeing at the start of the sentence. This, of course, would cause a change in emphasis, which may, or may not be appropriate in particular circumstances. But we digress.